# Using preg_replace_callback and create_function

Tags: php

I am trying to replace the words in a sentence using `preg_replace_callback`.

`"%1% and %2% went up the %3%"`

should become

`"Jack and Jill went up the hill"`

I have given my code below.

```
<?php
  $values = array("Jack", "Jill", "hill");
  $line = "%1% and %2% went up the %3%";
  $line = preg_replace_callback(
    '/%(.*?)%/',
    create_function(
        // single quotes are essential here,
        // or alternative escape all $ as \$
        '$matches',
        'return $values[$matches[1]-1];'
    ),
    $line
  );
  echo $line;
?>
```

What I am getting is

`" and  went up the "`

If I give `return $matches[1]-1;` , I am getting

`"0 and 1 went up the 2"`

Is it a scope issue ? How to make this working ? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a scoping issue - your anonymous function created by `create_function` does not have access to `$values`.

This should work (>= PHP 5.3.0)

```
<?php
  $values = array("Jack", "Jill", "hill");
  $line = "%1% and %2% went up the %3%";
  // Define our callback here and import $values into its scope ...
  $callback = 
    function ($matches) use ($values)
    {
      return $values[$matches[1]-1];
    };

  $line = preg_replace_callback(
    '/%(.*?)%/',
    $callback, // Use it here.
    $line
  );
  echo $line;
?>
```

By declaring the callback function with `use ($values)`, `$values` will be imported into its scope and available when it's called. This is the concept of a 'closure' over $values if you'd like to Google it further :).

Hope this helps.